# Line of Sight tool output does not match elevation of Sight Lines that are input

Tags: arcgis-pro, dem, line, elevation, 3d-analyst

I'm trying to use the Line of Sight (3d Analyst) tool to determine new building obstructions.  I have a DEM assigned to my scene and I have target and observation point feature classes with elevation from a field that I used to create Sight Lines with the Construct Sight Lines tool.  The elevation of the Sight Lines is set to a geometry z value at "Relative to Ground" and all line up with their actual physical location.  When I run the Line of Sight tool the resulting feature class appears lower than my Sight Lines which causes erroneous "Not Visible" features and obstruction points to be created.  The Line of Sight feature class lines up exactly with my Sight Lines if I change the elevation setting to "At an Absolute Height" but then they would be in the wrong location (lower).  How do I force the tool to use the correct elevation setting? Any suggestions or input greatly appreciated.

[image: Thick green line is Sight Line and thin green line is the Line of Sight tool output]

[image: Sight Lines Layer Properties]

[image: Line of Sight tool parameters]